# Rake routes 'match' mapping to the wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

My question has to do with mapping to controllers/actions using named routes.  I am trying to map '/profile' to 'customers#show'.  My routes file looks like this:

```
    root :to => 'pages#home'

  ## named routes
  match "profile" => "customers#show", :as => 'profile'
  match 'signin' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'signin'
  match 'signout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'signout'

  resources :customers do
    member do 
      get 'add_card'
      post 'submit_card'
    end
  end


  resources :payments, :only => [:show, :new]
    delete  'payments/delete_recurring_payment'
    post    'payments/submit_non_recurring'
    post    'payments/submit_recurring'

  resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy, :new]
```

Running 'rake routes' gives me this:

```
                         root        /                                            pages#home
                      profile        /profile(.:format)                           customers#show
                       signin        /signin(.:format)                            sessions#new
                      signout        /signout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
            add_card_customer GET    /customers/:id/add_card(.:format)            customers#add_card
         submit_card_customer POST   /customers/:id/submit_card(.:format)         customers#submit_card
                    customers GET    /customers(.:format)                         customers#index
                              POST   /customers(.:format)                         customers#create
                 new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                     customers#new
                edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                customers#edit
                     customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                     customers#show
                              PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                     customers#update
                              DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                     customers#destroy
                  new_payment GET    /payments/new(.:format)                      payments#new
                      payment GET    /payments/:id(.:format)                      payments#show
```

Here is where I'm stumped.  When I go to localhost:3000/profile I get a routing error saying this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers"}
```

This seems odd because there is indeed a route to 'customers#edit' due to my declaring customers as a resource.

However, when I go to 'localhost:3000/signin' I get routed to 'customers#show' which is where I want '/profile' to route to.

It seems like my routes are 'one off' in my routes file but I have no idea why.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE 1:  Adding my Customers Controller

```
   class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  layout "payments_layout"

  def show
    @customer = current_user
    get_account_info(@customer)
    get_payment_history(@customer, 10)
  end

  def new
     @title = 'Create an account'
     @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def edit
    @customer = current_user
    get_account_info(@customer)
  end

  def update
    @customer = current_user
    if @customer.update(params[:customer])
      redirect_to @customer
    else
      @card_message = "Use this form to add a credit card to your account.  You must have a credit card associated with your account in
                      in order to make payments on our system."
      get_account_info(@customer)
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
   @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
   if @customer.save_and_get_stripe_id
     sign_in(@customer)
     redirect_to @customer   
   else
     @title = 'Create an account'
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def add_card
    @customer = current_user
    get_account_info(@customer)
    @card_message = "Use this form to add a credit card to your account.  You must have a credit card associated with your account in
                    in order to make payments on our system."
  end

  def submit_card
    @customer = current_user
    res = @customer.add_or_update_card(params)
    if res
      redirect_to @customer
    else
      @error = res
      customer.get_account_info(@customer)
      render 'add_card'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you sahre your customers controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your views.

Do you have a link to edit your user profile?

It seems like you actually route to the right controller and action but have some links that rake can't route, e.g. you don't pass the ID to your edit_customer_path link.